# Graph API: Can I make multi-calls at a same time?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

In fact, I want to get the cover photo for each user's albums.

So, first I get the albums data:

```
$albums = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/me/albums",'GET');
```

Then I retrieve the cover_photo id and ask API to get details about this photo (such as the source)

```
foreach($albums as $album) {
     $data = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/". $album["cover_photo"], 'GET');
}
```

But this make a lot of calls to the API (one per album) and it's seems that she doesn't like.. Because my application return a timeout error.

Is there another way to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), or just use FQL. Something like the below would retrieve the `src` of all the album covers of the current user:

```
SELECT src 
FROM photo 
WHERE pid IN (
    SELECT cover_pid 
    FROM album 
    WHERE owner = me()
)
```

You can try it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20src%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20pid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20cover_pid%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%20=%20me%28%29%29). Obviously you can choose any field to retrieve from the [`photo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) table.

Comment: This works. I saw that we can also do this with the Graph API.
Like $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("?ids=1,2,3, 'GET'); Thanks.

Comment: As I said, you can use the Batch API if you want to use the Graph. But this specific task is much easier with FQL.

Comment: I agree. But, in fact, there is three methods: FQL, Batch API and just by specify "ids" in the Graph API. That's just what I want to say :)